# Xcode 15.0 Simulators Limited To Extremely Recent Devices and iOS Version

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode15

I just upgraded Xcode to version 15.0.

It seems now that the only available iOS runtime is 17.0.

I cannot add a simulator than uses a previous version of iOS, and certain devices are gone like iPhone 14.

Is this really the case -- that you can't test on devices/OSes more than a week old?

Seems very odd.

Comment: I'm not seeing this issue. If I go to the "Devices and Simulators" window and click the + icon at the bottom of the Simulators pane, I can choose any device from iPhone 6 through iPhone 15 and I can pick iOS 14, 15, 16, or 17 depending on the device I select. That iOS version also depends on what simulator runtimes you have installed in the Platforms tab of the Settings screen.

Comment: Hmm thanks.  Yes I see I am able to download previous versions now... but I am surprised it didn't keep my previous runtime 16.x from the previous installation of XCode.   I suspect it is hanging out on my harddrive somewhere.